# Opensuse and PulseAudio: Failed to initialize SDL: Could not setup connection to PulseAudio

Tags: linux, opensuse, pulseaudio, kdenlive

I am trying to open up `kdenlive` on an OpenSUSE system however I receive an error from the Terminal.

> Failed to initialize SDL: Could not setup connection to PulseAudio

When I try to open up `kdenlive` outside the Terminal I get the following:

> "Could not create the video preview window, something wrong with your
> install or driver settings".

I try to drag and drop an image into the environment but it crashes and closes.

The solutions online that I have seen are specific to Ubuntu and I can't seem to find a solution to an OpenSUSE issue.

## EDIT:

Here is a screen shot of the error after running `sudo snap install kdenlive --candidate` and then trying to open it.

[image]

Its in Spanish but it is saying the same message as above with the addition.

> Algo falló en la instalación de Kdenlive o en las preferencias del
> controlador. Por favor. solucionarlo.

- Something failed in the installation of Kdenlive or in the driver preferences. Please, fix it.

I click accept and it closes the program.

EDIT:

Added output from Terminal:

```
myUser@linux-9z5s:~> kdenlive
=== /// CANNOT ACCESS SPEECH DICTIONARIES FOLDER
=================BUILDING PROFILE REPOSITORY

========================
Invalid metadata for  "avcolour_space"
Failed to parse "avcolour_space"
Invalid metadata for  "avcolor_space"
Failed to parse "avcolor_space"
Invalid metadata for  "avdeinterlace"
Failed to parse "avdeinterlace"
Invalid metadata for  "swscale"
Failed to parse "swscale"
Invalid metadata for  "swresample"
Failed to parse "swresample"
Invalid metadata for  "audiochannels"
Failed to parse "audiochannels"
Invalid metadata for  "audioconvert"
Failed to parse "audioconvert"
Invalid metadata for  "imageconvert"
Failed to parse "imageconvert"
Invalid metadata for  "jack"
Failed to parse "jack"
Invalid metadata for  "glsl.manager"
Failed to parse "glsl.manager"
Invalid metadata for  "movit.convert"
Failed to parse "movit.convert"
Invalid metadata for  "movit.crop"
Failed to parse "movit.crop"
Invalid metadata for  "movit.resample"
Failed to parse "movit.resample"
Invalid metadata for  "movit.resize"
Failed to parse "movit.resize"
Invalid metadata for  "telecide"
Failed to parse "telecide"
Invalid metadata for  "deinterlace"
Failed to parse "deinterlace"
Unknown asset "avfilter.acompressor"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/acompressor.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.aecho"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/aecho.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.agate"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/agate.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.atadenoise"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_atadenoise.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.bwdif"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_bwdif.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.deblock"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_deblock.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.dedot"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_dedot.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.deflate"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_deflate.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.derain"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_derain.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.doubleweave"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_doubleweave.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.field"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_field.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.framestep"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_framestep.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.fspp"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_fspp.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.graphmonitor"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_graphmonitor.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.hqdn3d"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_hqdn3d.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.inflate"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_inflate.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.lagfun"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_lagfun.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.random"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_random.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.removegrain"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_removegrain.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.separatefields"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_separatefields.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.shuffleplanes"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_shuffleplanes.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.sr"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_sr.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.tmix"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_tmix.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.w3fdif"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_w3fdif.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.weave"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_weave.xml"
Unknown asset "avfilter.yadif"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/avfilter_yadif.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.baltan"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_baltan.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bgsubtract0r"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bgsubtract0r.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_eq_mask"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_eq_mask.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_eq_to_rect"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_eq_to_rect.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_hemi_to_eq"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_hemi_to_eq.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_rect_to_eq"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_rect_to_eq.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_stabilize_360"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_stabilize_360.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.bigsh0t_transform_360"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_bigsh0t_transform_360.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.delay0r"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_delay0r.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.delaygrab"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_delaygrab.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.facebl0r"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_facebl0r.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.facedetect"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_facedetect.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.lightgraffiti"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_lightgraffiti.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.lightgraffiti"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_lightgraffiti.xml"
Unknown asset "frei0r.tehRoxx0r"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/frei0r_tehroxx0r.xml"
Unknown asset "movit.unsharp_mask"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/movit_unsharp_mask.xml"
Unknown asset "region"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/region.xml"
Unknown asset "timewarp"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/speed.xml"
Unknown asset "vidstab"
==== PARSING ABORTED FOR:  "/snap/kdenlive/44/usr/share/kdenlive/effects/vidstab.xml"
Unknown asset "region"
ALSA lib conf.c:826:(get_char_skip_comments) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib conf.c:1967:(_snd_config_load_with_include) _toplevel_:13:19:No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4180:(snd_config_update_r) /etc/alsa-pulse.conf may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
no alsa devices available
kf.service.sycoca: Service type not found: "video/mlt-playlist"
kf.service.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kdenlive"
kf.service.sycoca: Service type not found: "application/x-kdenlivetitle"
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected nullptr parameter
qrc:/qml/timeline.qml:1903:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
MLT: "[consumer sdl2_audio ] Failed to initialize SDL: Could not setup connection to PulseAudio"
kf.notifications: Audio notification requested, but sound file from notifyrc file was not found, aborting audio notification
=== REG FOCUS:  false
=== REG FOCUS:  false
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Comment: Which variant of OpenSUSE are you using: Leap or Tumbleweed? Are you using Kdenlive through Snap/Flatpak?

Comment: Using OpenSUSE 15.2 and I don't know which one I am using Kdenlive through. How can I check?

Comment: Just installed it using `sudo snap install kdenlive --candidate` and a different version of kdenlive was installed. When I open it, I get the same error but this time is closes the application.

Comment: Ok, so you're using OpenSUSE Leap and, if I have understood you well, have installed `kdenlive` using Snap. Can you install `kdenlive` from the official repos (non-snap version) or try downloading and executing the binary (AppImage) from their [official site](https://kdenlive.org/en/download/) to see if the error persists? Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Snaps.

Comment: After downloading the `AppImage` I am getting the same error. I also tried the `Flatpak` version but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your error log again and, upon closer inspection, it seems like `MLT: "[consumer sdl2_audio ] Failed to initialize SDL: Could not setup connection to PulseAudio"` is the culprit. So I did some digging around and I found [this thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=172343).

Since Leap is the stable version of OpenSUSE, you might be out of luck for now. I guess the only thing you can do is to submit a bug report in Bugzilla and let the devs take care of it (eventually).

Sorry that it took me so long to answer, but I had forgotten about this thread.